# Ruby compile in windows with static socket

Tags: ruby, windows, sockets, compilation

I tried compile ruby2.1.5 source code with bat file like this.

```
..\ruby-2.1.5\win32\configure.bat --so-name ruby215 --disable-install-doc --disable-rubygems
```

And modified ext/Setup file to link socket module statically.

```
...
#sdbm
socket
#stringio
...
```

but I can't compile ruby well, compiler shows error like this.

```
...
linking shared-object socket.so
socket-i386-mswin32_110.lib 라이브러리 및 socket-i386-mswin32_110.exp 개체를 생성하고 있습니다.
init.obj : error LNK2019: _rb_w32_accept@12 외부 기호(참조 위치: _cloexec_accept 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
init.obj : error LNK2019: _rb_w32_connect@12 외부 기호(참조 위치: _connect_blocking 함수)에서 확인하지 못했습니다.
...
```

```
...
ifaddr.obj : error LNK2001: _rb_cNilClass 외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다.
ifaddr.obj : error LNK2001: _rb_cSymbol 외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다.
ifaddr.obj : error LNK2001: _rb_cTrueClass 외부 기호를 확인할 수 없습니다.
../../.ext/i386-mswin32_110/socket.so : fatal error LNK1120: 38개의 확인할 수 없는 외부 참조입니다.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : '0x2' 반환 코드입니다.
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : '0x2' 반환 코드입니다.
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\nmake.EXE"' : '0x2' 반환 코드입니다.
Stop.
```

I'm using VS2012 and used nmake in x86 native command line tool.
And the same error occurred with VC++ 6.0 cl.exe
add) can't compile ruby2.2.0 with same error.

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Will report back if I find a solution